# Failed to open stream permission denied

Tags: php, html, image

I am creating a profile image uploader, where the user can select a file and upload it, but I am getting this error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(user_files/profile_img/c3487ff77d.jpg) [function.move-    uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/lr/core/functions/users.php on line 4

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpi0WECJ' to 'user_files/profile_img/c3487ff77d.jpg' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/lr/core/functions/users.php on line 4
```

Line two through five is:

```
function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
$file_path = 'user_files/profile_img/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
}
```

And the rest in a loggedin.php file is:

```
if (isset($_FILES['profile_img']) === true) {
            if (empty($_FILES['profile_img']['name']) === true) {
                echo 'Please choose a file!';
            } else {
                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile_img']['name'];
                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile_img']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);
                } else {
                    echo 'Invalid file type! Allowed Types: ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($user_data['profile_img']) === false) {
            echo '<img src="', $user_data['profile_img'],'" alt="', $user_data['first_name'] ,'\'s Profile Image">';
        }
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong? Its not my .htaccess, it must be the code, but why?

Thanks

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong. You lack permission to move the file. You need to fix your filesystem/user permissions, which is completely external to the the code you've posted.

Comment: Make sure the folder you're trying to move the image to is writable by php

Comment: Okay, I'm on mac, how would I do this? I'm thinking making it readable and writable?

Comment: Okay, that worked, but now I am not getting an echo of the address?

Comment: @meagar What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are the permissions on the folder?  You may need to change it to enable PHP to write to it.

Comment: Okay, I made the file readable and writable. And the files are being put there, the php isn't echoing where the file will be put/

Comment: Oh, whoops, I forgot, Thanks